# How to individuate code between markdown in string

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring

I'm creating a textview where the user can insert snipets of code.
I want them to be able to insert markdowns like this:

> ``` some text here `

Then I want to individuate the text comprehended between the markdowns and apply to it some characteristics.

Assuming a string can contain more markdowns, how could I get all of the strings inside of the markdowns?

Let's say I have the following string:

> "In Swift a ```UIView` is An object that manages the content for a rectangular area on the screen. It subclasses ```UIResponder`. A ```UIPickerView` is a subclass of ```UIView`"

I want to individuate the substrings: UIView, UIResponder, UIPickerView, UIView.
Namely all the substrings comprehended between ```and `.

I have found some solutions which include using super complex for loops but I'm sure we have an easier way with some String method I can't use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regex like this -

````
import Foundation

let input = "In Swift a ```UIView` is An object that manages the content for a rectangular area on the screen. It subclasses ```UIResponder`. A ```UIPickerView` is a subclass of ```UIView`"
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(```.*?`)"#)
    let matches = regex.matches(in: input, range: NSRange(input.startIndex..., in: input))
    var results: [String] = []
    let nsStringInput = input as NSString
    for match in matches {
        results.append(nsStringInput.substring(with: match.range))
    }
    print(results)
}
catch {
    /// Handle error
}
````

Output -

````
[
    "```UIView`", 
    "```UIResponder`", 
    "```UIPickerView`", 
    "```UIView`"
]
````

Comment: Why would you include the `\`\`\` \`` in the results?

Comment: These results (along with their backticks) would give user the correct range in the string, that user is supposed to replace with new attributes (and new text without the backticks).

Comment: Sorry for getting back late, I loved the solution! just to know, what if I didn't want to include the backticks in the array?

Comment: Use `#"```(.*?)`"#` & `match.range(at: 1)` for regex pattern & `match.range` respectively. You can see it visually here - https://imgur.com/wUAF2Qu